# Mantaflow Smoke big and chunky

Tags: smoke-simulation, mantaflow

I am following along with this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4S6xSLKHoY&t=375s

Once he gets to the explosion effect part I start having issues. For some reason my smoke is big and chunky. I would like to slim them down and make them less square. I know I can increase the resolution divisions, but the tutorial guy is able to get a decent effect with only 128 divisions. Also my smoke does not show up in a render.
[image]

Comment: you should NOT always believe what you see in yt. I made yt tutorials myself and i just can tell: almost every video uploaded is cut, changed and improved in any thinkable way. And yes, of course, i do it too - because you don't wanna hear someone cough or throat... ;)

Comment: I can see that. He makes it look so quick and smooth with all the editing.